# dynamically load imageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, image-size

I have a layout where one imageView want dynamically load an image from drawable files. I want this I have a certain size imageView whatever drawable image, so you need to assign a size to upload. I searched the android developers but I've only seen functions to set the maximum height and width, but ir doesn't works.

I put the code:

```
image = getIntent().getExtras().getString("image");

ImageView paper = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Resources res = getResources();
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(image, "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(id);
paper.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Can you help please?
thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

and retrieve it on the other end:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");

//  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 250, 250, true);
img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: if i use a bitmap y should replace drawable for bitmap no?

Comment: thank you, but i obtain the name of the R.drawable.____ from the result of the function getIntent().getExtras().getString("image"). how can i replace the string image in this function bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image)? Can i delcare String path = "R.drawable.image" and call bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), path) this way?

Comment: If the image exist it would be better to pass uri in intent

Comment: sorry but i don't understand how pass uri in intent, can you say me any sample or worte the code? but anyway if not possible to convert the drawable to bitmap and then call bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 250, 250, true);
img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);?

Comment: Finally,the solution have been set a image in the imageView which has the size than i would want, and the i replace this image with image = getIntent().getExtras().getString("image");

ImageView paper = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Resources res = getResources();
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(image, "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(id);
paper.setImageDrawable(drawable);